# Separating Auth server and Resource server in oAuth 2.0

Tags: oauth-2.0

I am trying to create oAuth 2.0 app and have decided to separate Auth server and Resource servers. 
How should I go about maintaining state in Clients

Client will request for auth token to auth server. And auth server will verify and send in tokens. Till this part I understand. How should I now be using token. Should I be doing request to Resource server directly with access token and Resource server should verify that access token with Auth server? OR should I be first making request to auth server and then verify and forward request to Resource server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RFC (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) suggests:

> (F)  The resource server validates the access token, and if valid,
> serves the request.

but also that:

> The interaction between the authorization server and resource server
> is beyond the scope of this specification.

My instinct would be to have your resource server receive a request and then either validate the access token itself if possible - and otherwise query the auth server as necessary rather than have the auth server proxy requests.

Comment: I will accept this answer. That is what i think i should do aswell. Thank you

Comment: Where should the login part be? in Auth server or resource server itself?

Comment: I'd expect your auth server to be the one that issues the access token.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing Protected Resources

The client accesses protected resources by presenting the access
   token to the resource server.  The resource server MUST validate the
   access token and ensure that it has not expired and that its scope
   covers the requested resource.  The methods used by the resource
   server to validate the access token (as well as any error responses)
   are beyond the scope of this specification but generally involve an
   interaction or coordination between the resource server and the
   authorization server.

The method in which the client utilizes the access token to
   authenticate with the resource server depends on the type of access
   token issued by the authorization server.  Typically, it involves
   using the HTTP "Authorization" request header field [RFC2617] with an
   authentication scheme defined by the specification of the access
   token type used, such as [RFC6750].